# @Embedded object gererating CROSS JOIN on JPQL

Tags: jpa, entity-relationship, cross-join

i'm try use JPA @Embedded object in Entity. That Embedded has @OneToOne relationsip, but wen i try get filter using JPQL. there is generating CROSS JOIN, but i expected INNER JOIN. See the axample:

```
 @Entity 
    Class A{
        @Id
        Long id;

        @Embedded
        private B b;  
    }

    @Emdeddable
    Class B{
        @OneToOne
        private C c;  
    }

    @Entity
    Class C{
        @Column
        private name;  
    }
```

In database, the FK column to "C" table is in "A" table. When i try this JPQL: `SELECT FROM a WHERE a.b.c.name = :name` i expected JPA does the folowing: `A inner join C on A.id=C.id`, but JPA does `A cross join B where A.id=B.id`

I dont want put C relationship in entity A becouse my specific code organization. Have any solution to this? Is this a bug?

Comment: "JPA" doesnt do anything, your JPA provider does. Perhaps mention which one it is

Comment: Sorry. I1m using JPA 2.1 with  Hibernate 5 and Jboss EAP 7.